# Обновление формулы в OpenOffice Writer

Tags: формулы, open-office, excel-формулы

Есть таблица в OpenOffice **Writer** (не Calc).

В одной из ячеек есть сумма, которая посчиталась формулой.

1. Как сделать, чтобы значение само обновлялось при изменении данных в таблице?
2. Как редактировать введённую формулу?
3. Как разделить результат (сумму) на 8?

PS: Нагуглить не получается, всё попадается про Calc.

Comment: 1. Не надо было в формулу текстовые ячейки включать. Заработало.

Comment: Не, не заработало... Глючит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверено на версии OpenOffice Writer

```
AOO411m6(Build:9775)  -  Rev. 1617669
2014-0Gh8-13 09:06:54 (Mi, 13 Aug 2014)
```

1. Имеем таблицу из столбцов `Продукты`, `Цена`:

[image: Таблица примера]

2. Строку суммы записываем в следующей нотации `=<B2:B5>`.

Для вставки формулы используем `F2`, формула начинается с `=`. Ограничения метода  - пересчет происходит автоматически при изменении значений в столбце `Цена`. При добавлении строк требуется изменять нижнее значение индекса строки (`B5` в нашем примере)

[image: Вставка суммы по столбцу]

3. Для деления суммы на `8` достаточно по `F2` в формуле суммы дописать `/8` (Финальная версия формулы `=<B2:B5>/8`).

[image: Деление суммы на 8]